# Using Database in Android just like MS Access

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to make a database about "Calories Calculating". This is just for me to use so I don't need any professional features.

Actually I've been using Excel and Access for a long time, so I am very accustomed to use GUI spreadsheet or database program. However, I think SQlite is very hard to make a query, jusk like MS Access I think.

***Please recommend me a program which I can use just like Access on Android.***
Or, let me know how to make query in SQLite... I know how to make tables though...
Also, I could only do very easy tasks like "Hello Android"... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class to do it for you:

```
public class MyDataOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    MyDataOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "DATABASE_NAME", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tablename (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "column1 TEXT, column2 TEXT, column3 INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor getMyCursor() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename", null);
    }
}
```

Now just make your object, and call getMyCursor()

```
MyDataOpenHelper mydata = new MyDataOpenHelper(context);
Cursor cursor = myData.getMyCursor();
```